# Access object property in array angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array of objects, each object contains weather info about some location. I have problem when I want to access speficif object proprety in array. Return undefined.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(WEATHER_ITEMS);
    console.log(WEATHER_ITEMS[0].cityName);
```

CLASS

```
 import { CurrentWeather } from './current-weather';

    export const WEATHER_ITEMS: CurrentWeather[] = [

    ];
```

SERVICE

```
  addWeatherItem(weatherItem: CurrentWeather){
    WEATHER_ITEMS.push(weatherItem);
  }
```

[error and array info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUQRm.png)

Comment: seems this might be some kind of async operation? If so, please post that code too, or do you really have just the console logs in `OnInit`?

Comment: @shawtky Show us your whole `forecast.component.ts` please.

Answer (score -1):

cityName is present is object CurrentWeather. So first access CurrentWeather then cityName

```
WEATHER_ITEMS[0].CurrentWeather.cityName
```

Comment: Property 'CurrentWeather' does not exist on type 'CurrentWeather'.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(WEATHER_ITEMS[0]); in ngOnInit().

Comment: output is: undefined

Comment: As said by AJT_82 the array gets filled asynchronously. So data will be available  after service has added data. ngOnInit is invoked before service has added data.